# Get full products single pages for a product category on a single post in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I am looking for a code to show full product informations (title of the product, buy button, image gallery, description and so on) for all products of a specific product category of my choice on one single post.

There is not actually any shortcode for this and I don’t have the skills to write something by myself.

Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom shortcode That is using the existing [**`[product_page]`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-10) woocommerce shortcode in a loop, to output all single product pages for a defined product category (one after the other).

This custom shortcode has 2 arguments:

- **`cat`** for the product category *(slug)*
- **`limit`** for the number of posts to be displayed *(default is all)*

The code:

```
if( !function_exists('single_product_pages_by_category') ) {

    // Add Shortcode
    function single_product_pages_by_category( $atts ) {

        // Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'cat' => '',
                'limit'   =>'-1'
            ),
            $atts, 'product_pages_cat'
        );

        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => $atts['limit'],
            'tax_query'      => array( array(
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'field'      => 'slug',
                'terms'      => $atts['cat'],
            ) )
        ) );

        $output = '<div class="products-in-'.$atts['cat'].'">'; // DIV container html tag (opening)

        // Iterating though each product in the defined category
        foreach( $posts as $post ){
            $post_id = $post->ID; // The Product ID
            // Using WooCommerce [product_page] existing shortcode in the loop
            $output .= '<div class="product-'.$post_id.'">' . do_shortcode ( "[product_page id=$post_id]" ) . '</div>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>'; // DIV container html tag (closing)

        // Always return the output (never echo)
        return $output;
    }

    add_shortcode( 'product_pages_cat', 'single_product_pages_by_category' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and Works in WooCommerce 3+

---

**USAGE** (example for 'posters' product category slug):

```
[product_pages_cat cat="posters"]
```

Comment: hey. thank you a lot for this! actually it's not working 100% as i thought it would work. it shows every product below each other but the description is missing and it always shows "similar products" below each product which is shown. is it possible to place "similar products" only once at the end of the post, below the last product shown? and to add description to every product shown?

Comment: That's how it looks like at the moment: http://adventskalenderkaufen.de/katzen-adventskalender/